# VS2012 compiles to x86 with "Any CPU" in a x64 OS

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, dll, compilation

I have a solution with a C# project and a C DLL. The solution is set to "Mixed Platforms" and the C# project to "Any CPU".

When the DLL is set to compile for x64, I get a crash. But when the DLL is set to compile for x86, everything works fine.

The OS is Windows7 x64.

Environment.Is64BitProcess gives false no matter which I try.

My understanding is that "Any CPU" would compile to x64 by default since the OS is x64. Clearly, I am wrong.

Thank you guys.

Comment: This is a usability nightmare in Visual Studio, VS2010 really screwed this up.  The solution's Platform name is irrelevant to C# projects, it only matters to C++ projects.  There's only one setting you care about, right-click your *EXE Project*, Properties, Build tab, Platform target/Prefer 32-bit.  Set it both for the Debug and Release configurations.  You want x86 here to keep the C code happy.

Comment: Yes, the "Prefer 32-bit" flag was set. After messing around a bit with those options, I got it to work for x64 and Any CPU. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

> My understanding is that "Any CPU" would compile to x64 by default

Nope, it'll compile to "Any CPU". What it runs as depends on **what machine is executing it**. So if you are *running* it on a 64-bit CPU, then yes, it will run as 64-bit. However, from the crash, it sounds like your C dll is 32-bit, or you are using 32-bit API calls. In which case you will need to compile it for 32-bit. Note that in VS2013 there is also a "Prefer 32-bit" option for "Any CPU", which will run as 32-bit unless 32-bit simply isn't available. Most people want to turn this *off* ;p

Note also that if this is a *library* (from the dll tag), it will also depend on whether the *process* is 32-bit vs 64-bit.

Answer (score 2):

First we should now what is  [Platform target](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zekwfyz4.aspx):

`anycpu` (default) compiles your assembly to run on any platform. Your application runs as a 64-bit process whenever possible and falls back to 32-bit when only that mode is available.

`anycpu32bitpreferred` compiles your assembly to run on any platform. Your application runs in 32-bit mode on systems that support both 64-bit and 32-bit applications. You can specify this option only for projects that target the .NET Framework 4.5.

`ARM` compiles your assembly to run on a computer that has an Advanced RISC Machine (ARM) processor.

x64 compiles your assembly to be run by the 64-bit common language runtime on a computer that supports the AMD64 or EM64T instruction set.

`x86` compiles your assembly to be run by the 32-bit, x86-compatible common language runtime.
`Itanium` compiles your assembly to be run by the 64-bit common language runtime on a computer with an `Itanium` processor.

So `anyCpu` means run 32bit and 64bit depend on your cpu.I think your dll is 32bit so yo can use `x86` or `anycpu`.